# how correctly insert lambda expression into another one translated to sql?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda

```
    internal IEnumerable<Setting> Search(string text)
    {
        Func<string, string, bool> searchCI =
            (x, y) => x.IndexOf(y, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
        return _dc.Settings.Where(
            x => searchCI(x.key, text)
                || searchCI(x.description, text) );
    }
```

this code generates exception: {"Method 'System.Object DynamicInvoke(System.Object[])' has no supported translation to SQL."}

help to fix, plz

UPD:

```
internal IEnumerable<Setting> Search(string text)
{
    return _dc.Settings.Where(
        x => x.key.IndexOf(text).StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
            || x.description.IndexOf(text).StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
}
```

this works but duplicate code. how can i make a subexpression can be compiled to sql (if possible)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because EF don't know how to convert your lambda expression in native MSSQL query format.

Solution:

```
 internal IEnumerable<Setting> Search(string text)
    {
        Func<string, string, bool> searchCI =
            (x, y) => x.IndexOf(y, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
        return _dc.Settings.ToList().Where(
            x => searchCI(x.key, text)
                || searchCI(x.description, text) );
    }
```

You can use SQL server profile to get the result query.

Comment: yes, the other working variant can be seen in upd

(and seems better to me, because do not lead to loading full Settings table)

but it leads to code duplicatication and i tried to simplify code by moving duplication to searchCI subexpression. my question is how to do it (if possible).